# Can we truncate tables in cassandra, If any one of the node is down

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

In my Project I am using Cassandra for DB, 3 nodes have created for this. Here the problem is some times due to disk space issue, one of the node is going down, at that time I tried to truncate the tables, but I am not able to truncate them, I am getting something like `CONSISTENCY LEVEL` related issue. So what I am doing is, I am moving some data to another location then restarting the cassandra, once it is up then I am truncating the tables. Here my question is, without making the one node `up`(Out of 3 nodes), can we truncate the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need all nodes available or the command will fail.

> TRUNCATE sends a JMX command to all nodes, telling them to delete SSTables that hold the data from the specified table. If any of these nodes is down or doesn't respond, the command fails and outputs a message like the following:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlTruncate.html

Comment: I am not getting an error like
`Unable to complete request: one or more nodes were unavailable`
I am getting error like the bellow one
`<stdin>:1:TruncateError: Error during truncate: Cannot achieve consistency level ALL`

Comment: Okay, the documentation might a bit wrong but in this case they both mean the same: There are not enough nodes available to fulfill the request.